# Regex: Allowlisting URL Top-Level-Domains

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that allowlists specific TLDs in the URL scheme. Most of my tests are passing except for ones that repeat the TLD:

**Regex**

```
^https:\/\/[^\/]+\.my-site\.com|cloud\/?.*?$
```

**False Positive**

```
https://qa.my-site.cloud.cloud/check-this-out?check-it-out=true
```

This is showing as a valid match according to the regex, but I want to exclude matches that have repeated TLDs (i.e. .cloud.cloud from the example above). How do I avoid the regex matching URLs with repeated TLDs? Adding a group and `{1}` did not solve the problem: `^https:\/\/[^\/]+\.my-site\.(?:com|cloud){1}\/?.*?$`

Language being used is Javascript.

Comment: Please add a bit more information. Include several test cases, or it's hard to figure out exactly what you want. If I understand correctly, you want the URL to be in the format of `https://{one-subdomain}.my-site.{com or cloud}`? Are you aloud to have multiple subdomains?

Comment: Clarified my ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You need to wrap alternation (`|`) in parentheses: `(com|cloud)` instead of `com|cloud`
2. The `/` should be required if there is a path to the URL

Here's a working regex:

```
^https:\/\/[^\/]+\.my-site\.(com|cloud)(\/.*?)?$
```

[Try it.](https://regex101.com/r/JzTDkX/2)

Comment: @S.C. in addition to regex101 that `@`code linked to, you can see a generated diagram at [regexpr.com](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Ehttps%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%2B%5C.my-site%5C.%28com%7Ccloud%29%28%5C%2F.*%3F%29%3F%24%2Fgm)

Comment: @StephenP that's awesome, never seen that tool before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookahead assertion to ensure that the TLD only appears once in the domain:

```
^https:\/\/[^\/]+\.my-site\.(?=com|cloud)[^\/]*\/?.*?$
```

Explanation:

- `^https:\/\/[^\/]+\.my-site\.` matches the start of the string, "https://" and everything up to ".my-site."
- `(?=com|cloud)` is a positive lookahead assertion that ensures the TLD is either "com" or "cloud"
- `[^\/]*\/?` matches the rest of the domain path, including the TLD, but not including any trailing slash (if there is one)
- `.*?$` matches the rest of the URL, including any query parameters

Note that the TLDs are listed inside a non-capturing group (?:com|cloud), which means they will be treated as one option and not capture any matching groups.